# URL rewrite outbound rules and custom error pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting, custom-error-pages

I'm using Application Request Routing to proxy a blog into a larger website. I'm using the following rules to rewrite the URI-based attributes on HTML elements to ensure the generated HTML conforms to the proxy configuration:

```
<rule name="HtmlContentRewrite" preCondition="HtmlContent" stopProcessing="false">
    <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Frame, Head, IFrame, Img, Input, Link, Script" pattern="^/([^/].*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" value="/blog/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Now this works perfectly fine for all content, with the exception of custom error pages. The custom error pages are basicaly MVC views at /e/not-found, etc., but the rewriter isn't performing it's work on custom error pages, so my content is left unstyled and without images where it is failing to load those resources.

Does anyone know if URL rewriting outbound rules can actually be applied to custom error pages? If not, any suggested workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to stub out your custom error pages as redirects that go to a normal URL to allow URL rewriting to occur.